# Dynatrace springboot configuration apitoken and uri gets null

Tags: spring-boot, dynatrace

I am adding dynatrace configuration in springboot. In the application.yml file the following things are added

[image: dynatrace configration]

When running project, i am getting this exception,

[image: exception]

The uri and api-token are returning null.
Expecting application to run